# Do matters pass through each other if there is no repulsion?

Tags: forces

Physicists told us that we don't actually "touch" the chair we are sitting on, rather, we are hovering on top of it. I wonder if this repulsion between atoms is not there between my butt and my chair, would I just drop onto the floor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not just drop onto the floor, you would drop right through the floor. How do we know this ? We have an example of matter that does exactly this - neutrinos.

Neutrinos are particles of matter that are created in the nuclear reactions in the Sub and other stars. They are unaffected by the electromagnetic force and by the strong nuclear force. Billions of neutrinos pass right through every square centimetre of your body (and, indeed, right through the Earth) every second, and neither you nor the neutrinos are affected.

Comment: Haha ok, its hard to imagine. Would the chair still hold its shape when I drop through it?

Comment: @user1589188 in fact nothing will hold any shape since that relies on the EM force to bind molecules and atoms together.

Comment: I will guess though, if a matter passes through a matter then it will break the Nuclear Binding Energy of one of the matter or both which will result in the liberation of energy.

Comment: How do you define "matter"? Are neutrinos "matter"?

Comment: @Triatticus right I get that, but I was wondering if it was just the repulsion between my butt and the chair that disappeared, while the force that holds my body and the chair was still there.

Comment: @user1589188 The force that holds your body and the chair together is *the same* force that creates the repulsion between them - it is the electromagnetic force in both cases. So you cannot have one without the other.